# Why doesn't $location.path fire the $routeProvider function?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build my first AngularJS single page application.  I copied part of the code below and modified it some.  I have a menu bar which calls the Navigate method that I added to the mainController.

When I click on the menu button the expected alert message appears in Navigate, but the alert message in the $routeProvider function only fires when the application starts and it never fires again.  I can't find a good explanation of this, but logic says the $routeProvider function should fire when a new $location.path is set in Navigate.  Is that wrong?  How is this supposed to wire up?  Is my nested single page controller causing the menu command to fail?

Also, are there really supposed to be two semicolons at the end or should one of them come after the app.config section?

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
    {
        alert("$routeProvider " + $routeProvider.path);
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'App/Views/Home.html',
              controller: 'homeController'
          })
          .when('/about', {
              templateUrl: 'App/Views/About.html',
              controller: 'aboutController'
          })
          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
          });
    }])

    app.controller('mainController', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.Title = "Default Title";
        $scope.Message = "Default Message";

        $scope.Navigate = function (myPath)
        {
            alert("Navigate " + myPath);
            $location.path(myPath);
        };
    });;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul class="MenuBar">
        <li class="MenuButton FloatLeft" ng-click="Navigate('/home');">Home</li>
        <li class="MenuButton FloatLeft" ng-click="Navigate('/about');">About</li>
        <li class="MenuButton FloatLeft" ng-click="Navigate('/about');">Log In</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You only need one semicolon after each component you've attached to the module.

Comment: How is your Navigate function being called currently?

Comment: mario, like this: <ul class="MenuBar">
    <li class="MenuButton FloatLeft" ng-click="Navigate('/home');">Home</li>
    <li class="MenuButton FloatLeft" ng-click="Navigate('/about');">About</li>
    <li class="MenuButton FloatLeft" ng-click="Navigate('/about');">Log In</li>
</ul>

Comment: I'm sure the Navigate function is firing because I see the alert appear from the Navigate function.

Comment: But I don't think the $routeProvider function is on a controller.  It's on config (remember I'm pretty new to this).  So how do I get the $routeProvider function to fire when the Navigate function changes $location.path?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. So you're trying to figure out why the `alert` from within the `config` is not firing?

Comment: Yes, but Dr. Cool below says it only fires once at startup.  So now my question is why doesn't setting $location.path in the Navigate function cause the controller to fire?

Comment: See the new answer I just posted.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `<a>` tags and `ng-href`?

Comment: Because I already had a menu template that uses <ul> and <li>.  I didn't want to have to rework all the formatting to get a link to look like the <li> elements, and it seems to me that it should work with most any HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run an alert whenever the `$routeProvider` function runs but it doesn't quite work that way.  The `$routeProvider` function just tells Angular "Whenever the location path changes, refer to this JSON object to know what to do next."  Then your code providers some JSON attributes to Angular such as `templateUrl` and `controller`.  Your alert function will only run once because the `$routeProvider` is just setup code to configure Angular's routes.

To run code after going to another "page", just add the code to the controller.

Code Example:

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http) {
    alert("I'm running the homeController() function now");
});
```

Also, I noticed that you didn't inject `$location` into your controller.  Without this, `$location` will just be an undefined object.  Change your controller definition like this:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $location)
{
    $scope.Title = "Default Title";
    $scope.Message = "Default Message";

    $scope.Navigate = function (myPath)
    {
        alert("Navigate " + myPath);
        $location.path(myPath);
    };
});
```

Remember that any Angular object starting with the `$` dollar sign (`$timeout`, `$http`, `$routeProvider`, etc) must be injected into your controller.

Comment: Dr. Cool - So I think you're saying the config function is set up at the start and never needs to run again because it will automatically connect those paths to the correct templateUrl and controller.  But that's not happening when $location.path is called in Navigate.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that Angular doesn't seem to be catching the route and actually sending you to the new template and controller?  It could be that Angular isn't matching the route path properly.  Just for fun, try setting ``Navigate('/home')`` to ``Navigate('#/home')`` and tell me what happens.  If that fixes it, I'll tell you why.  If not, then please explain a little more about the problem and what exactly you're expecting to happen.

Comment: Dr. Cool - see the new answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with the code you're showing. Not enough details to know for sure but here's what's wrong.

**First:**

A module's `config` block will only be executed once, at the start. You're not seeing the `alert` within your config beyond once because it's only ever called once during the bootstrap of your module.

**Second:**

You need to inject services that your controller depends on.

> `app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) { });`

Note that you're missing the `$location` service here.

`app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $location) { });`

**Third:**

We can't see some missing pieces to your code to help you out. You're not showing us how `mainController` is actually hooked up to anything. How `myPath` is being sent to the `Navigation` function on your controller, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nested controller that I wasn't using.  When I took that out part of the menu worked.  I say part because on some links instead of calling the Navigate function I was setting the window.location.  That seems to fire the $routeProvider and the view changes like it should.  When I change the Navigate function as shown below it works.  I think setting $location.path() in the Navigate function should do the same thing, but it's not working for me.

```js
$scope.Navigate = function (myPath)
{
    alert("Navigate " + myPath);
    //$location.path(myPath);
    window.location = '#' + myPath;
};
```

Comment: I just found the problem.  Check my updated answer.  That should fix it.

Comment: Dr. Cool, I forgot to inject $location as you noted.  So I tried that in the Navigate function and setting $location.path(myPath) still doesn't work.  I'm going to use window.location unless someone comes up with a $location.path solution that works for me.  Thanks.